# equation Solution Set in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, math, mathematical-optimization

i have a problem that i should make a programme to solve this equation

> a2 + b2 + c2 = d

and sort the solution in `Lexicographical order`  the order comes without make it and if there is no solution print -1 so i write my Code and i use three nested loops

```
d=int(raw_input())
p=0
for a in range(d+1):
    a
    for b in range(d+1):
        b
        for c in range(d+1):
            c
           if a**2+b**2+c**2==d:
                 p=1
                 print a,b,c
                 break
if p==0:
    print -1
```

my problem in Time Limit exceeded The input range is 10^5 simple input and output to be clear

```
6
```

output

```
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
```

any ideas To Avoid that Time Limit?

Comment: Hint: why not assume that `a >= b >= c` to save repeating a whole bunch of triplets, `a`, `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice that your break statement breaks only out of the most inner for loop.
you may want to use p for that and make checks at the end of each for loop, i.e (it wasn't checked...):

```
d=int(raw_input())
p=0
for a in range(d+1):
    a
    for b in range(d+1):
        b
        for c in range(d+1):
            c
           if a**2+b**2+c**2==d:
                 p=1
                 lst =  [a,b,c]
                 lst.sort() 
                 for num in lst:
                    print num,
                 break
        if p==1:
            break
    if p==1:
        break

if p==0:
    print -1
```

Comment: okay but it does not print them arranged it print one line only i want it printed in three line sorted in Lexicographical order my code printed them sorted but that work but not sorted them

Comment: I fixed it, now it should work.. I need to wipe off my python-rust :)

Comment: i want the output like i refer in the question ? not in one line and the answer not one line if i enter 50 for example  it have many probabilities